# Anvil from Guru blender not exporting with all materials and textures to glb file for WebGL

Tags: export, gltf, webgl

I cannot for the life of me figure out why my Anvil model from the famous Guru Blender series tutorial will not export to a glb file for use with WebGL. Since I made it in Blender 2.79b, I have been opening it up in Blender 2.8 and have tried exporting as a glb, gltf, and gltf with separate files.

None of them show all the textures, normal maps, and material design when using glTF Viewer online; the closest I have come is using the GLB packer, but it turns out unlike the Blender file render at all. I have had errors saying a node was empty, which I have no idea where that's at, and I also have had errors saying the images are not a power of 2. When resizing the images even to powers of 2, still doesn't work. I'm completely lost in the sauce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glTF 2.0 has a specific PBR material model, for transfer to realtime rendering engines.  It cannot support arbitrary arrangements of Blender nodes, as WebGL wouldn't be able to handle realtime rendering of arbitrarily complex Blender nodes.  Instead, the glTF material definition has a strict number of fields, corresponding to a particular interpretation of physically-based materials.

The Blender Manual documents [how to export materials to glTF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#materials).  The short version is, you'll need to adapt your material node setup to use primarily images connected to the Principled BSDF node.